# How is a difference-in-differences model represented in a causal diagram (or directed acyclic graph)?

Tags: difference-in-difference, treatment-effect, dag, causal-diagram

Unlike a standard causal model with A = Treatment, X = Confounder, and Y = Outcome:

[image]

a difference-in-differences (DiD) model is concerned with estimating the Average Treatment Effect on the Treated (ATT) $= E(Y_1-Y_0|A=1)$.

Hence we're interested in the causal effects of confounders on the trends in the outcome over time (pre and post periods) between the treatment and control groups. (See see [Daw & Hatfield (2018)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1475-6773.12993) and [Zeldow & Hatfield (2021)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33978956/))

Therefore, for the purposes of drawing a DiD causal diagram is it as simple as replacing Y with ATT:

[image]

or perhaps $Y_{post} - Y_{pre}$?

Comment: Personally, I don't think these graphs are as effective as intended because they stress the variables considered, while a Diff-in-Diff is all about the design/strategy (comparing Treated & Control, Before & After). In particular, these graphs totally lack the time dimension. I do prefer graphs as the one in Figure 5.2.1 in 'Mostly Harmless Econometrics', of the type reported in Wikipedia too under "Difference in differences".

Comment: @Alessandro After some hunting I found a DiD causal diagram on the Health Policy Data Science Lab website (https://diff.healthpolicydatascience.org/#confounding) - scroll down a little. They split the outcome variable Y into Y1 and Y2 for the pre and post periods, so that a confounder is causally linked by arrows to both Y1 and Y2.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing!!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here, the outcome of interest
is the difference between the pre- and post-treatment period, $Y1 - Y0$. This difference is influenced by the
treatment, unobserved factors $U$, and observed covariates $X$. The dashed arrow between $U$ and $A$ indicates a
statistical dependency between the variables, but where we remain agnostic to the precise causal mechanism.
For example, in the minimum wage example, $U$ might be the average income in restaurant’s neighbourhood,
which is dependent on the state, and hence also the treatment.

Source:https://github.com/probml/pml2-book/releases/tag/2022-10-16

Comment: Thank you - this book looks like a good reference. Now I've read three different sources that describe three different ways to represent the outcome in a diff-in-diff causal diagram: as either (1) $Y_1 - Y_0$, or (2) $Y_1$ and $Y_0$ excluding $Y_1 - Y_0$ (Zeldow & Hatfield), or (3) all three quantities $Y_1 - Y_0$, $Y_1$ and $Y_0$ linked in the same diagram, with $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ having deterministic relationships with $Y_1 - Y_0$ (Pearl). The question is which one is correct?